# How to get $$.Map.Item after a fail and catch in an AWS State Machine inside an inline Map?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a state machine with a Map that executes the same process for multiple items in parallel:

```
"Each Item": {
    "Type": "Map",
    "ItemsPath": "$.items",
    "ItemSelector": {
        "item.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value"
    },
    "MaxConcurrency": 40,
    "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
            "Mode": "INLINE"
        },
        "StartAt": "Process Item",
        "States": {
            "Process Item": {
                "Type": "Task",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:MyFunction",
                "Catch": [
                    {
                        "ErrorEquals": [
                            "HandledError"
                        ],
                        "Next": "fallback"
                    }
                ],
                "End": true
            },
            "fallback": {
                "Type": "Task",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:MyOtherFunction",
                "End": true
            }
```

The first step "Process Item" gets item object from input defined by ItemSelector. It can then pass on the item object in the output to the input of next step. But if it fails and "Catch" sends execution to "fallback" step the input of the step is the error details. How can "fallback" step get the item object of this Map iteration? For some reason $$.Map.Item is only available in ItemSelector. For steps definitions "$$" points at the initial whole of execution details, no Map details..